# What is the time complexity of this code snippet? O(n) or O(logn*logn)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

```
for(int i=1;i*i<N;i++)
{
    for(int j=1;j*j<N;j++)
    {
     // print something
    }
}
```

My book shows that the answer is O(n). I think it should be O(logn^2).

Why is the answer O(n)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer loop iterates over `i` for `i=1,2,...,sqrt(N)`, same for the inner loop; so in total you get `O(sqrt(N)*sqrt(N))` which is `O(N)`.

Comment: Yes you are right. I got confused between log(n) and sqrt(n). Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Logarithms require repeated multiplication or division to achieve. So `log(N)` would have looked like: `for(int i=1;i<N;i=i*c)` or `for(int i=N;i>1;i=i/c)` , where  `c > 1`. Generally, `c=2`.